# Increment second column with matched first column

Tags: linux, shell

I have text file with data given below and I want to **increment uidNumber by 9000** and all data should remain same.

Input file:

```
cn: cn=DINAKAR PERI_DPA062,ou=DBS,dc=xyz,dc=com

objectClass: posixAccount

objectClass: inetOrgPerson

objectClass: extensibleObject

cn: DINAKAR PERI

uidNumber: 1001

dn: cn=JOSEPH ABBY_AJA059,ou=TSR,dc=xyz,dc=com

objectClass: posixAccount

objectClass: inetOrgPerson

objectClass: extensibleObject

cn: JOSEPH ABBY

uidNumber: 1002

.

.

.

.
```

Output file:

```
only uidNumber should be like this 

cn: cn=DINAKAR PERI_DPA062,ou=DBS,dc=xyz,dc=com

objectClass: posixAccount

objectClass: inetOrgPerson

objectClass: extensibleObject

cn: DINAKAR PERI

uidNumber: 10001

dn: cn=JOSEPH ABBY_AJA059,ou=TSR,dc=xyz,dc=com

objectClass: posixAccount

objectClass: inetOrgPerson

objectClass: extensibleObject

cn: JOSEPH ABBY

uidNumber: 10002

.

.

.

.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/uidNumber/{$2+=9000}1' infile
```

Two separate actions here:

1. `/uidNumber/{$2+=9000}` : Only when pattern is found increase second field
   (numeracilly)
2. `1`: Always print current the line.

Comment: Glad it dids, you can mark the answer then @user2074481

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in the file "testdata", then:

With pure bash:

```
RE="uidNumber:"
while read -r line
do
    if [[ $line =~ $RE ]]
    then
        read -r key val <<< "$line"
        val=$(( $val + 9000 ))
        echo "$key $val"
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < testdata
```

check:

```
diff <(bash incscript.sh) testdata
```

prints:

```
11c11
< uidNumber: 10001
---
> uidNumber: 1001
23c23
< uidNumber: 10002
---
> uidNumber: 1002
```

And, possible with perl too, for example:

```
perl -plE 's/(\d+)/@{[$1+9000]}/c if /uidNumber/'
```

check:

```
diff <(perl -plE 's/(\d+)/@{[$1+9000]}/c if /uidNumber/' < testdata) testdata
```

prints:

```
11c11
< uidNumber: 10001
---
> uidNumber: 1001
23c23
< uidNumber: 10002
---
> uidNumber: 1002
```